# How does promise make code asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I know we all use promises to avoid function callback hell, but my question is where in the event loop the promise code runs and whether the code is really asynchronous.

I mean, is this code asynchronous just because it's run within a promise?
Or is the promise not a part of the event loop?

```js
const p = new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{

  resolve('am i part of the event loop ?  , am i a diffrent thread ? or am i synchronized? ')

})
```

Comment: "_How does promise make code asynchronous_" It doesn't, it expects the passed function to call something async.

Comment: none of the code in the question runs asynchronously

Comment: @c69: resolve and reject are **not** *called asynchronously*, it is your function passed to the promise constructor that calls them. And the function is executed synchronously by the promise constructor. It is the body of the function that can introduce asynchronicity (but it's not required). As long as there is nothing async in the function, both res and rej are called synchronously.

Comment: if the code included the standard (only) method of "accessing" the resolved value ... i.e., `.then` ... then you would have asynchronism in the code you posted

Comment: @WiktorZychla is it not true that whatever you add inside .resolve() is treated as async, since it gets pushed to the end of the event queue and won't run until it gets picked up?

Comment: @LinasMickevicius: `resolve` only sets the "returned" value. What is pushed to the end of the event queue is whatever you attach to the promise with `then`. If there is nothing attached, `resolve` itself doesn't push anything to the event queue.

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla - good catch. I meant "success and fail callbacks in .then". Args resolve and reject are just a way to control the executor function (which is an argument to constructor).

Comment: @WiktorZychla Thanks, I see what you mean, .then is what makes it async, resolve just holds the return value. By the way how is this implemented behind the scenes, is it using something like setTimeout 0?

Comment: @LinasMickevicius: yes, could even be `setImmediate`, point is just to make it to the end of the queue, without blocking current execution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How does promise make code asynchronous?

It doesn't.

A promise provides a standard interface (e.g. with a `.then()` method) for handling asynchronous functions.

If everything done inside a promise is non-asynchronous, then the code is still non-asynchronous.

```js
const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log(1);
  resolve();
  console.log(2);

});
console.log(3);
```

You can see, above, that the Promise is blocking just as any other non-asynchronous code is.

Comment: Uhhh, with a slight complication that `.then()` handlers are always called asynchronously.  Perhaps worth a clarification on that point.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript we can not create a synchronous function. There are set predefined asynchronous function and we can use them to make our code asynchronous. These asynchronous function generally takes a callback function as argument to perform tasks on completion of asynchronous task.

Promises are synchronous, `.then()` is a asynchronous function. In async-await `await` is asynchronous and anything written after await is executed after asynchronous await.

```
function main(){
  console.log(2);
  return new Promise( (re,rj) => {
    console.log(3);
    re(4);
    console.log(5);
    rj(6);
    console.log(7);
  });

}

console.log(1);

main()
.then( r=> {
  console.log(r)
})
.catch(e=>{
  console.log(e)
});

console.log(8);
```

As expected output is

```
1
2
3
5
7
8
// asynchronous .then function
4
```

Similar thing happen when we use setTimeout, setInterval, API call, fs functions, all asynchronous thing happen at browser/kernel then all callback happens at our Javascript single thread.