# "Who" execute async functions in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been struggling with the following question for a long time with no answer, and yes i've searched the internet for quite some time.

When i have an async function ( a one that return a Promise ) either by the `async` keyword (implicitly) or `return Promise` (explicitly), who execute that code ?? i mean the event loop continue, yet this code get executed ?

my thoughts are:

1. the code is executed when the event loop is in "idle" mode
2. some other "external/worker" thread execute it.

will appreciate your support.

Comment: Some other code makes a call to the function.

Comment: They're all executed by the CPU, unless you spawn some external worker threads for them (which are also executed by the CPU lolz. thanks @Pointy)

Comment: @lanxion I bet the external threads are also executed by the CPU :)

Comment: well yeah lol, probably should have phrased it better

Comment: Functions which return promises are executed the same as any other. [A promise is nothing executable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49685827/1048572).

Comment: If we get past the technicality of what a Promise is, as stated above ^.    Where it gets executed it could be any number of places, although wasteful it could get executed in the main thread, it could be a worker thread, or even a newly spawned one.  Unless PC architecture has changed dramatically over the years, it could even be an IRQ.

Comment: @Keith No PC operating system will run JavaScript in an ISR

Comment: @Bergi In node.js the physical file io is not coded in Javascript.  This is my take anyway on what the OP was trying to understand.  IOW: when that async function, maybe `fs.readFile` etc is run.  I'm not sure on what nodejs runtime uses for fileio, but at a hunch it's using a worker thread, that could ironically be using overlapped IO too.  I would think the OS would nowadays only have direct access to Interrupt's,  but I do remember writing TSR's in the good old DOS days, and from what I can remember used Interrupts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. The code is executed on the main event loop as soon as the function is called.

[Promises aren't themselves asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47391272/how-does-promise-make-code-asynchronous). They are tools for managing asynchronous code.

If something asynchronous happens *inside* the function, then how that gets executed is up to that specific bit of code.

Comment: so simple, fair enough :) thanks - will accept the answer.